# How to run "try" block until valid input is provided

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, user-input

To begin with, I don't understand why a code that stands after the `catch` block gets executed in case of error whose `-ErrorAction` is set to `Stop`. And the original question has to do with my intent to ask a user for input again in case it was invalid. I want to get code execution back to the `try` block from the `catch` block. Your thoughts and help are appreciated.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    [ValidateRange(5,9)] #Enter some other number to trigger an error.
    [System.Byte]$cInput=Read-Host "Enter a number from 5 to 9" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Verbose "Invalid input. Try again." #I want to go back to the "try" block here.
}
Write-Output "Thank you." #Why is this still executed in case of error?
```

Thank you

EDIT: You would need the following to see the verbose message

```
$VerbosePreference="Continue"
```

Comment: `-Stop` converts a non-terminating error into a terminating error, otherwise it wouldn't even trigger the 'catch' block. Terminating errors only end the script completely if they are uncaught, otherwise you catch them and (presumably) handle them apprpriately, and the script carries on. It's the code after the error, *inside the try block* which doesn't run. See the (small) [`PowerShell Big Book of Error Handling`](https://www.gitbook.com/book/devopscollective/the-big-book-of-powershell-error-handling/details)

Comment: Thank you for responding and clearing some things up.

If you took your comment and added a mention of "do-while" loop to it with an example and posted it as an answer I gladly would have marked it as such.

Comment: While the linked question is not an exact duplicate, I hope between  @TessellatingHeckler's helpful comments and the answers to the linked question you'll find what you need.

Comment: @mklement0 Since both questions are essentially about input validation in a loop I consider this pretty much an exact duplicate. The `try..catch` bit is just an X to the actual Y problem.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Understood, though my sense is that Ben could have used a little more explicit help with the `try..catch` part, but fortunately TessellatingHeckler has provided that, so I think we're all on the same page now.